# Images inside iframe require authorization

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, iframe, http-authentication

I'm working on a page with a few iframes. The sites displayed inside the iframes are all secured with http auth, so i've set the iframe src like this

```
<iframe src="http://username:password@some.web.site"></iframe>
```

**the problem:**
The sites load, but not the images. For each image i get a 401 (authorization required) in the console.

Am i missing something?

**EDIT:** it seems to be a "Chrome-only" problem

Answer (score 2):

By any chance is this occurring with Chrome only?

*Edit:

If you add this to the end of the browser .exe:
--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt

As in:
C:\Users\HelloItsMe\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt

It should allow the images to load.  I suspect this is a bug with Chrome though.

Comment: Yes. I switched to Firefox after struggling with this problem and everything works fine